# Одеть и надеть

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как будет правильно?

> Не знаете, что одеть на первое
> свидание?

или

> Не знаете, что надеть на первое
> свидание?

Answer (score 4):

Что *надеть* на первое свидание. *Надеть* — на себя или на кого-то, *одеть* — кого-то. К примеру: как одеть дочку на первое свидание.

Но, но, но!

Формы типа "одеть [на себя] пальто" стали настолько популярны, что их вот-вот признают допустимыми разговорными. Так считают некоторые лингвисты.

К своему стыду, я всегда говорю "я одел пальто". "Надел" кажется мне чересчур "книжным". ))) Но вот **писать** нужно, конечно, "надел".

Answer (score 1):

НАДЕТЬ можно что-то (на кого-то или на что-то). А ОДЕТЬ можно кого-то (во что-то).

Надеть перчати, одеть ребёнка.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаете, что надеть на первое свидание.

Выбрать верное слово из "надеть", "одеть" помогают глаголы обратного действия:
парным к "надеть" является "снять", а к "одеть" -- "раздеть". Из этого следует, что нельзя одеть одежду.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, не все со мной согласятся, но я бы сказала: "Что одеть на первое свидание?". (А то получается, что я хочу надеть нечто не на себя, а на свидание).

И попробую объяснить свою точку зрения. Мне кажется, что выбор одеть/надеть поддерживается немного искусственно, чтобы мы помнили о грамотности. Интересный вариант дается в толковом словаре на Грамоте.ру: ОДЕТЬ,  кого-что (во что). Дождь на улице, оденьте ребёнка в плащ! Ну кто так будет говорить? Постепенно предлог В затерялся в современной речи.

Да и классики наши тоже не всегда соблюдали это выбор, например:Офицер окинул его с ног до головы несколько удивленным взглядом, улыбнулся слегка, пожал плечами и беспрекословно помог одеть пальто (Ф. М. Достоевский. Дневник писателя).

Answer (score -1):

Одеть используется для одушевлённых, надеть - для неодушевлённых, так что здесь зависит от контекста. Если Вы предлагаете кому-либо, то одеть. Если Вы предлагаете что-то, то надеть/
Так что я Одел пальто и пальто НАдели. Т.е. пальто может быть только надетым, а человек одетым (в пальто, например)

Comment: Одеть пальто нельзя!

Answer (score -4):

Лингвистика - чрезвычайно закомплексованная наука. Наука, основанная на справочниках. Кто не с нами - еретик. Здесь вам скажут "как", но никогда не скажут "почему". Нейрофизиолог, взглянув на  энцефалограмму активности мозга, зафиксировал бы реакцию в разных участках коры г/мозга. Надеть и Одеть. Действие одно, варианты, которые решает ваше подсознание - разные. Подсознание принимает решение намного раньше, чем мы осознаём это сознанием. Вы ещё не знаете, как пройдёт ваше свидание, а компьютер уже просчитал варианты развития событий. От того, какой вариант вы выберете, будет зависеть исход свидания. Буква Н, например, вызовет ответную реакцию в той части вашего "Я", которая отвечает за приобретённый вами багаж знаний (пережитый опыт).

P.S. Вам бы на другой форум, но, к сожалению, на данный момент не существует науки о "времени", ибо это и есть "царица", кладезь всех знаний. А лингвистика всего лишь ветвь, такая же, как математика, физика и т.д.